# Non-exhaustive patterns in my function

Tags: haskell

The following function compiles but when run outputs a non-exhaustive pattern error

```
hufMerge :: CodeTable -> CodeTable -> CodeTable
hufMerge [(x,a)] [(y,b)] = foldr (:) (map add0 [(x,a)]) (map add1 [(y,b)])
hufMerge [(x,a)] [] = map add0 [(x,a)]
hufMerge [] [(y,b)] = map add1 [(y,b)]
hufMerge [] [] = []
```

where

```
type CodeTable = [(Char,[Integer])]
```

I am not seeing where the error is coming from, do I have to do 2^4 cases, where out of [(x,a)] [(y,b)], x, a, y, or b can be zero?

Comment: This doesn’t work when you pass a list with a length greater than one.

Comment: I highly recommend putting the pragma `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-incomplete-patterns #-}` at the top of your source file (above any actual Haskell code). Much of the time, you should explicitly define "can't happen" cases as errors. In performance-critical code, you should instead use laxer patterns along with assertions.

Comment: For example, if you're defining `f :: Int -> Int` and you *know* the argument will always be either 1 or 2, you can write `f 1 = 5; f x = assert (x == 2) 6`, which will compile to the same code as `f 1 = 5; f _ = 6` when assertions are turned off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you meant

```
hufMerge :: CodeTable -> CodeTable -> CodeTable
hufMerge [] [] = []
hufMerge xs [] = map add0 xs
hufMerge [] ys = map add1 ys
hufMerge xs ys = foldr (:) (map add0 xs) (map add1 ys)
```

If you match on `[foo]` you're matching on a list of *exactly* length one and then matching on that one element with whatever pattern `foo` is.

As a quick catalog on how to match on lists,

1. Ignore them completely, as always `_` ignores the value
2. Match with any variable, The pattern `xs` for example will bind with any list
3. Match head-tail, `(x:xs)` will bind the first element to `x` and rest to `xs`
4. Match element-wise `[x, y, z ...]` which is just sugar for `x : y : z .... : []`